# How to show modal notification on page load if sending mail is successful in laravel?

Tags: laravel

My code is like this.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mailModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="mailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index:10000000;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ Session::get('message') }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endif
```

Mail is sending successfully and also message is generating successfully but modal is not showing on page load. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Make sure the jquery is loading from the `<head></head>` block and also check the console tab to identify the issue.

Comment: Did the above comment answer your question?

Comment: Yes.Thanks.The jquery was at the bottom.